On the Lipschitz constant outside the stretch set
Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a Lipschitz map. We define the local Lipschitz constant $Lf$ of $f$ at $x \in \mathbb R^n$ by
$$Lf(x) := \lim_{r \to 0_+} \text{Lip}(f, B_r (x)),$$
where $\text{Lip}(f, U) := \sup_{y,z  \in U} \frac{f(y) - f(z)}{y- z}$ denotes the Lipschitz constant of $f$ on the set $U$.
Define the stretch set $S$ of $f$ by
$$S := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \, | \, Lf(x) = \text{Lip}(f, \mathbb R^n)\}.$$
Roughly, the stretch set is the set on which $f$ achieves its maximal Lipschitz constant.
Question: Is it true that $\text{Lip}(f, \mathbb R^n) = \max(\text{Lip} (f, S), \text{Lip}(f, \mathbb R^n \setminus S))$?
Remark: The stretch set plays a crucial role in Thurston's "best Lipschitz maps" approach to Teichmuller theory, see here for a reference.

The set $S$ may be reduced to a single point, like for $f(x):=\arctan x$, or be empty, like for $g:=x-\arctan x$. What is $\text{Lip}(f,S)$ in these cases? (Not very relevant, as in these cases  $\text{Lip}(f,\mathbb R^n\setminus S)= \text{Lip}(f,\mathbb R^n)$  )

@PietroMajer Ah, let us say that we set those cases to be $0$ by convention.

In fact $\text{Lip}(f,\mathbb R^n)=\max\big( \text{Lip}(f,A), \text{Lip}(f,A^c)\big)$ holds for every $A\subset \mathbb R^n$.

The inequality $\text{Lip}(f,\mathbb R^n)\ge\max\big( \text{Lip}(f,A), \text{Lip}(f,A^c)\big)$ is clear.
For the opposite inequality, let   $x\in A$ and $y \in A^c$. So we have $\partial A\cap[x ,y ]\neq\emptyset$: let $z \in \partial A\cap[x ,y ]$. Since
$$
\|y -x \|=\|y -z \|+\|z -x \|,
$$ the quotient
$\frac{f(y )-f(x )}{\|y -x \| } $ is a convex combination of $\frac{f(y )-f(z )}{\|y -z \| } $ and $\frac{f(z )-f(x )}{\|z -x \| } $ (here with the convention  “$\frac00=0$” stated in comments), so
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\|f(y )-f(x )\|}{\|y -x \| } & \le\max\left(\frac{\|f(y )-f(z )\|}{\|y -z \| },   \frac{\|f(z )-f(x )\|}{\|z -x \| } \right)\\ 
& \le  \max\left( \text{Lip}(f,\overline{A}), \text{Lip}(f,\overline{A^c})\right)\\
& = \max\left( \text{Lip}(f,A), \text{Lip}(f,A^c)\right),
\end{split}$$  and the inequality follows.


Ah, it holds in general. I think I focused too much on the specific definition at hand and didn’t see the simple general proof. Nice!

What about a finite partition, e.g. $\mathbb R^n=A\cup B\cup C$?  I’d say  $$\text{Lip}(f)=\max\big(\text{Lip}(f,A), \text{Lip}(f,B), \text{Lip}(f,C)\big),$$ but it’s not  quite clear.

Hm yes because now in this case we don’t necessarily have a nice intersection to exploit. That seems subtle indeed.

Would you like to post this as a seperate problem? I think it is quite interesting.

One may consider a covering into (wlog) closed sets $A_j$, and also define, with the obvious meaning, $\lambda_{ij}:=\text{Lip}(f,A_i,A_j)$. There are a number of inequalities between these constants
